# geom_raster with colors based on specific discrete values

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, classification, geom-raster

I'd like to plot a geom_raster with colors based on a specific classification:
[image]

I tried the following code (variable = SPI) but it didn't work:

```
scale_fill_gradient(colours = c( "brown","burlywood","bisque","aliceblue","cadetblue2","blue"), 
                      breaks=c(-2,-1.5,-1,1,1.5,2), labels = format(c("-2","-1.5","-1","1","1.5","2")))
```

Example:

```
year <- seq(1977,2021,1)
jan = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
feb = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
mar = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
apr = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
may = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
jun = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
jul = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
aug = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
sep = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
oct = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
nov = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)
dec = runif(45, min=-4, max=4)

df = data.frame(year,jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec)
df <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "year")

df$year <- factor(df$year, levels = (unique(df$year)))
df$variable <- factor(df$variable, levels = (unique(df$variable)))

library(ggplot2)
e1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = year, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster()+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Bohicon"))+
  scale_fill_gradient(colours = c( "brown","burlywood","bisque","aliceblue","cadetblue2","blue"), 
                      breaks=c(-2,-1.5,-1,1,1.5,2), labels = format(c("-2","-1.5","-1","1","1.5","2")))+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

e1
```

Many thanks and kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a column that classifies your continues values into different classes and then use it to manually set the colors you want.

```
df$col <- as.factor(findInterval(df$value, c(-2,-1.5,-1,1,1.5,2), all.inside = T))

ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = year, fill = col)) +
  geom_raster() +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Bohicon:")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values  =c( "brown","burlywood","bisque","aliceblue","cadetblue2","blue"),
                    labels = format(c("-2","-1.5","-1","1","1.5","2"))) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

## Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I may have missed something but I think you may need another break to get the cuts shown in the table. I've also added another colour in the plot on this account. I've not checked that the cuts and labels match.

```r
df$val_cut <- cut(df$value, breaks = c(-Inf, -2, -1.5, -1, 1, 1.5, 2, Inf), 
                  labels = c("<= -2", "-1.99 to -1.5", "-1.49 to -1", " -0.99 to 0.99", "1 to 1.49", "1.5 to 1.99", ">=2"))

library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.3
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = year, fill = val_cut)) +
  geom_raster()+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Bohicon"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "brown","burlywood","bisque","aliceblue","cadetblue2","blue", "black"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In response to OP's later question...
Yes you could present the data in a bar graph although `geom_bar` would not be the preferred approach as the data is already summarised.
Here is a possible solution using `geom_col` and `facet_wrap` just to make the data readable. I've  assumed you want to view monthly values by year, but you can adjust the data as suits your requirements.

Also added some formatting to help with legibility.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(y = value, x = variable, fill = val_cut)) +
  geom_col()+
  facet_wrap(~year) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Bohicon"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "brown","burlywood","bisque","aliceblue","cadetblue2","blue", "black")) +
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is it work with geom_bar?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want the plot to look like with regard to `geom_bar` but the additional code should be enough to get you started.